# Getting E: Footer is wrong E: signature verification failed in upgrading new OTA(Custom AOSP)

Tags: android, android-source, recovery, ota

I have created 3 major OTAs.

upgrading OTA from V010  to v030 is working perfectly.
but OTA upgraded from v020 to V030 getting 
**E: footer is wrong E: Signature Verification Failed**

V010 - basic OTA.

V020 - added some android apps in this version.

V030 - Resolved some issues with wifi and BT sound in framework level.

I unable to understand V020 OTA to V030 OTA is not upgrading.

I thought some recovery issue but its working perfectly from V010 OTA  to v030 OTA.

Can you please help me.

Comment: please add more details of your V020. With the current information we can only guess what your problem could be.